# Swift 2.x to swift 3, XCode complaining error : Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift

Here is my swift 2.X code that does'nt work any more on swift 3 :

```
var dictThemesNamesStyles=[String:[Int:Int]]()
self.styles=dictThemesNamesStyles
let keysArray:Array=Array(self.styles.keys)
let sortedKeysArray = keysArray.sorted(by:
{
    (str1: NSObject, str2: NSObject) -> Bool in
    return Int((str1 as! String))<Int((str2 as! String))
})
self.stylesLevel1Keys=sortedKeysArray
self.styleThemesPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

On line :
"return Int((str1 as! String)) < Int((str2 as! String))"
it complains with the error : "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

What do I have to change in this code to make it work ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the type of `keysArray`? Btw that `keysArray:Array` should result in a compile time error as well, there's no `Array` type, `Array` is a generic type (`Array<Element.Type>` is a valid type, such as `Array<Int>`).

Comment: `Int(String)` returns an optional. You can't use `<` with optional values.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Not to mention that the `:Array` isn't necessary *anyway*, since the type system already knows this will be an array by virtue of the fact that you're assigning the result of `Array`'s initializer to the variable. Just `let keysArray = Array(self.styles.keys)` is sufficient.

Comment: @DávidPásztor here is part of code coming before my last code : <code>var dictThemesNamesStyles=[String:[Int:Int]]()       self.styles=dictThemesNamesStyles      How can change this line "return Int((str1 as! String)) < Int((str2 as! String))" to make it work ?

Comment: There's not even a need to convert `self.styles.keys` into an `Array`. It's already a `Collection`, it can be `sorted` to produce an array, directly.

Comment: `sortedKeysArray` will always be empty, because `keysArray`, `self.styles.keys` and `dictThemesNamesStyles` are all empty.

Comment: And if all of the keys in the dictionary are string representations of `Int`s, why not just use the `Int`s as keys, directly?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this line by line:

```
var dictThemesNamesStyles=[String:[Int:Int]]()
self.styles=dictThemesNamesStyles
```

Okay, we've got a dictionary of strings to dictionaries of integers.

```
let keysArray:Array=Array(self.styles.keys)
```

There are a few problems with this line:

1. The declaration of `:Array` without a generic parameter.
2. The type declaration is unnecessary, since the type system already knows this is an `Array`, since you're calling `Array`'s initializer.
3. *Creating this whole Array* is unnecessary, since we're just passing the result to `sorted`, which already exists on the collection returned by `keys`, and which will return an `Array`. Creating the array is therefore a needless performance hit which we should avoid.

I would, in fact, delete this entire line, and just replace `keysArray` with `self.styles.keys` in the next line:

```
let sortedKeysArray = self.styles.keys.sorted(by:
```

Next:

```
{
    (str1: NSObject, str2: NSObject) -> Bool in
    return Int((str1 as! String))<Int((str2 as! String))
```

Okay, we've got a few problems here.

1. `str1` and `str2` are declared as `NSObject`, when they are in fact `String`s.
2. Consequently, the `as! String` casts are unnecessary.
3. `Int(String)` returns an Optional, so you need to take into account the case where the result may be nil. I'd just provide a default value; probably `0`, although you could also use a `guard` statement to throw an error if you prefer.

In general, there's a lot of verbosity here. This whole closure can actually be succinctly written as a one-liner:

```
let sortedKeysArray = self.styles.keys.sorted { (Int($0) ?? 0) < (Int($1) ?? 0) }
```

Anyway, take care of these issues, and your code will compile.

Comment: Thnks for your complet explanation... but when I try to simplify as you told by "let sortedKeysArray = self.styles.keys.sorted { (Int($0) ?? 0) < (Int($1) ?? 0) }" it still complains this : "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'int' with an argument list of type '(AnyHasable')"

Comment: Thanks for your complet explanation... but when I try to simplify as you told by "let sortedKeysArray = self.styles.keys.sorted { (Int($0) ?? 0) < (Int($1) ?? 0) }" it still complains this : "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'int' with an argument list of type '(AnyHasable')"

Comment: @Zipette As I said in the other comment thread, you need to fix your `styles` property. It is probably an `NSDictionary` (which gets interpreted by Swift as `[AnyHashable : Any]`). You need to change this to a Swift dictionary type.

Comment: Ok thks I fixed style and defined it as swift dictionary but now it complains : "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" on the line let sortedKeysArray = self.styles.keys.sorted { (Int($0) ?? 0) < (Int($1) ?? 0) } . Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: What's the type of `styles` now?

Comment: It's defined like that in its class: "var styles = [String: [Int: Int]]()" . Do I have to replace with var styles = Dictionary" ? Thks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

That all seems pretty complex. You can simplify this quite a bit:

```
self.styles = [String: [Int: Int]]()

self.stylesLevel1Keys= self.styles.keys.sorted { Int($0)! < Int($1)! }

self.styleThemesPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Comment: Curses! Beaten to the punch by my propensity to explain everything. This is good, although I'd get rid of the force-unwraps and use `?? 0` instead. A possible mis-sort is better than a possible crash IMO.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I would rather it crash and force OP to confront their misassumptions about their data. They really should be using Ints as keys, in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, that is rather strange that `String` is being used to store integer data.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka IMHO, I think people underestimate the danger of silent failure, and are too rigid about "No force unwrapping, ever". There are plenty of situations where encountering `nil` is devastating to a program's execution, completely unrecoverable, and no course of action makes sense besides crashing to prevent corruption of user data, bugs down the line, etc.

Comment: Yeah, but this isn't one of them IMO. This is just sorting items, probably for display. A silent failure in this sort algorithm isn't going to be the end of the world. A few items may appear in the wrong order; this is preferable to a crash. Much less annoying from an end-user's point of view, without a doubt. IMO of course.

Comment: I do agree that OP should replace the keys with `Int` to sidestep this whole problem altogether, though.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka You can't know for sure. Perhaps this is just for display, and some items will be out of order in the UI. No big deal. But what if OP tries to do a binary search through this, and erroneously concludes an element is not present in the array because it was out of position? My point is that such a silent failure could lead to a hard to debug situation, in which this failure manifests by causing some other kind of failure down the line

Comment: @Alexander It seems a very good simplification : self.stylesLevel1Keys = self.styles.keys.sorted { Int($0)! < Int($1)! } but now XCode complains this : "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'int' with an argument list of type '(AnyHasable')"

Comment: @Zipette Well why the hell are the `self.styles` keys `AnyHashable`, rather than `String` or `Int`? Your datatypes are whack, mayne

Comment: @Alexander Fair enough. Although for the case where `nil` is unrecoverable, I still prefer to use `guard` to catch this case, and then `throw` an error. This way, we can exit gracefully with an error message explaining what went wrong instead of just unceremoniously crashing with no explanation.

Comment: @Zipette Yeah, fix the type on your `styles` property. I suspect it's probably declared as an `NSDictionary`; change that to a proper Swift dictionary type ([`String` : [Int : Int]]`, or even better, `[Int : [Int : Int]]`)

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I agree with that. I wish force unwrapping yielded better debug information, like a filename, line number, a quote of the expression it and an arrow pointing to which `!` caused it

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, the reason I dislike force-unwrap is because it's such an easy Band-Aid to slap on your code without having to think about what it really means if `nil` shows up, leading to mysterious crashes that just make your app look like an unstable POS from the end-user's point of view. :-/

Comment: @Alexander sorry but I did'nt do this part of code so I don't understand it very well, some one could correct it in order it works ? Sorry...

Comment: @Zipette What's the type of the `styles` property? If it's `NSDictionary`, change it.

Comment: @Zipette Get used to it. 99% of the code I've ever worked on was written by someone else. You have to be adaptable.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Yeah, I like the idea of using `guard` + `preconditionError` as a way of not only adding debug information to my essentially forced unwrapping, but also to communicate to future readers of my code that my psuedo-force unwrapping was well considered, and not just a band-aid